# how to restore a single "View" in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I know how to restore a single table form postgresql database backup file.

For Example: To restore password_history table i use the below command and it works fine.

```
pg_restore --data-only --table=password_history C:\Users\sjayaram\Desktop\dcmdb-01-17-2014-10-19-18.backup > passwordhistory.txt
```

Whats the command to restore a single "View" from postgresql database backup file.

Comment: Have you tried `pg_restore --schema-only --table=password_history ...`

Comment: pg_restore --schema-only this command shows only the schema of the table. But i need the View i.e the Views that we create by combining the table.